# LI element in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

for some reason my LI elements are not floated to the left in internet explorer, they are showed each below the other. Anybody knows how I could fix this?

```
#books ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
#books ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: could you provide the html and css? does it work in other browsers, etc?

Comment: I added the css to the question. Yes, it works fine in firefox.

Comment: Are you using compatibility view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, it may have to do with setting display: inline.  Changing to display:block; seems to solve the issue in IE and FF.

```
#books ul{
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
float:left;
display:block;}
```

#books ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;}

Comment: They're by default already block, so I would just remove the entire property.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use float, if you just want each LI to be inline you can use just the display property.

```
#books ul{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
#books ul li{
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```